# how to make wallpaper changing app programatically in ios?

Tags: ios, wallpaper

I want to make an ios app that changes the wallpaper, lockscreen and app icons.
I have googled it a lot and got same ans that apple doesn't allow this. But on itunes I saw a app named "magic theme" which does this. Here is [the link](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/magic-theme/id901198042?mt=8).

Can someone tell me the trick how can I do this in my app?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. The app your link provides is for creating / designing or modifying existing wallpapers. Changing apps icons is also not possible. Read the apps description carefully and try it yourself so you see what it does.

For things like changing icons and wallpapers you'd need to jailbreak your device and roll your app using Cydia.

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/app-icons/id749100888?mt=8  this app actually changes the icons of app installed in your iphone.

Comment: and magic theme app changes the wallpapers and lock screen of your iphone. If apple doesn't allow this then how can magic theme app is able to change lockscreen and wallpaper?

Comment: The first app you linked to simply creates a web clip icon on your device that loads the original app via its url - it won't work for apps that don't have a custom app url and it doesn't replace the app icon, it just creates a second one

Comment: And if you read the reviews of Magic Theme it is clear that you need to activate the modified wallpapers in settings as most people don't think it is a very good app

Comment: thanx.. now i got the actual functionality of magic theme app.. it just save the selected wallpaper to camera roll folder from where we have to manually go to settings app and change wallpaper.