# Swift - Change iPhone background

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, wallpaper

I was thinking about changing iPhone background using app. Is there some code in Swift to change iPhone background?

I don´t mean change background of app. I mean change background totally of the iPhone.

Comment: The tags of your question are not relevant

Comment: no, you can't do it from an app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to make wallpaper changing app programatically in ios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26096849/how-to-make-wallpaper-changing-app-programatically-in-ios)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no way to currently access the device's Wallpaper as of now.

Essentially Apple doesn't allow it, though jailbroken devices can access this functionality.

You also aren't allowed to set or change the wallpaper of the entire phone in third party apps. The user has to do that manually through the settings or photos app. You can add instructions as to how the user can do that in your app.