# Can I change iOS Screen wallpaper programmatically In Swift 5 and IOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, imageview, wallpaper

I want to change Home Screen and lock screen wallpaper of iOS 12

Comment: It's impossible.

Comment: No it's not possibles for now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - Change iPhone background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50598159/swift-change-iphone-background)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Short answer:

> In one word it is not possible. In Apple devices, There is no provision for the change iOS Screen wallpaper programmatically. The user has to do that manually through the settings or
> photos app. For things like changing wallpapers, you'd need to jailbreak your device.

## Long answer:

Before iOS 9.0, There is some hack which is worked perfectly. Unfortunately, from iOS > 9.0 there is no alternative.

Refer [CMFWallpaper](https://gist.github.com/camdenfullmer/b287f634acd089f4b92f). Maybe it will help you.

> Set the wallpaper (lock and/or home screen) on iOS using Apple's
> private API. Please be aware that including this code in an App Store
> submission will result in a rejection.