# App is being restarted for os12+ devices while set wallpapers in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, wallpaper

App is being restarted for os12+ devices(only for androids) while set wallpapers in flutter

I have used wallpaper: ^1.1.0 plugin for set wallpapers

App should not being restarted while set.

Comment: ios did not support set wallpaper

Comment: ios did not allow other apps to change wallpapers and lock screen

Comment: its only for android @AliHassan

Comment: yes ios did not have an api for changing wallpaper

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**Wallper Plugin only for android**

Ios did not have an api for changing wallpaper

[Stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56112014/can-i-change-ios-screen-wallpaper-programmatically-in-swift-5-and-ios-12)

Comment: I have clearly mention that issue is for only android