# Set wallpaper from widget screenshot in flutter

Tags: flutter

Hey I need to take a screenshot of widget in flutter and then set wallpaper from it,can anyone help .Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [screenshot package](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot) to take the screenshot. With help of the [path_provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider), you can save it to a specific location, if you want to. Then, use the [wallpaper_manager package](https://pub.dev/packages/wallpaper_manager) to change the wallpaper on the device‘s home screen or lock screen or both.

Though, the wallpaper_manager package only works on Android devices since iOS doesn‘t allow it. As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26096849/how-to-make-wallpaper-changing-app-programatically-in-ios), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50598159/swift-change-iphone-background) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56112014/can-i-change-ios-screen-wallpaper-programmatically-in-swift-5-and-ios-12), this was never possible on iPhone (or at least not intended by Apple) and probably won’t become possible in near future. However, if you want your application to work on iOS as well, you can still save your wallpapers to the user’s photo gallery and include instructions on how to change the wallpaper manually.

Since your going to need quite a bit of source code to make it work, I will not provide any code snippets here. Please consult the package‘s documentation to learn how to do it. Side note: I recommend using the [provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) to handle taking screenshots and setting wallpapers because it allows you to access these functionalities easily from everywhere in your source code and keep your background logic separated from the UI, which will make your code far more readable.

Comment: Hey nicolas, Actually i need to take a screenshot programmatically not manually and same goes for wallpaper too.....i dont want user to to do it manually.... Its a wallpaper app

Comment: Now I understand it, thank you for the explanation. I changed my answer accordingly. Please consider accepting my answer if it helped :)

Comment: Thank you so much Nicolas for your help .... Your guidance helped me a lot

Comment: Glad I could help! [This article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/export-your-widget-to-image-with-flutter-dc7ecfa6bafb) might be interesting for you as well. It explains how to export a widget as a Base64 String, which you can convert to a .png file, for instance. [Here](https://bezkoder.com/dart-base64-image/) you‘ll find some help with decoding the Base64 String.